# Bamboo: how to produce maven artifact

Tags: maven, bamboo, artifact

I've set up a Bamboo server and made a test project and plan with a Maven build task.

But this task doesn't produce any artifacts (except, maybe, test results, which I've unchecked). And I'd like to have all maven artifacts to be attached to the build results, like it is done in Hudson.

How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find some info on the [Bamboo documentation](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Configuring+a+Job%27s+Build+Artifacts).

This is for the latest Bamboo release (v3.4).

Also, are you running Maven with the goal `package` (or `install`) ?

Comment: I'm doing clean deploy, which includes both package and install.

Comment: Oh! I didn't notice the 'Create Definition' button out there. Many thanks!