# MAVEN build does not generate jar

Tags: maven, build, bamboo

I am using Atlassian Bamboo, and Maven 3 plugin. When I push my code and build the project, it does not seem to be creating a jar, therefore it can not publish it. You can see my logs and pom here

https://gist.github.com/bozmen/d842d9a3f9cb9b73559caa5658d11c27

or here

```
// log

simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:36    Build MavenTest - Merge - Build Job #51 (MERGE-MERGE-JOB1-51) started building on agent Second Local Agent
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:36    
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:36    Build working directory is /opt/atlassian/home/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/MERGE-MERGE-JOB1
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:36    Executing build MavenTest - Merge - Build Job #51 (MERGE-MERGE-JOB1-51)
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:36    Starting task 'Checkout Default Repository' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.vcs:task.vcs.checkout'
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:36    Updating source code to revision: 23b69330c4527209f95f1b4c3aa1f0a7db70cc55
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:36    Fetching 'refs/heads/master' from 'ssh://git@stash.solveka.com.tr:7999/merge/maventest.git'.
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:36    Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:38549' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:37    Checking out revision 23b69330c4527209f95f1b4c3aa1f0a7db70cc55.
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:37    Previous HEAD position was add3546... fsg
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:37    HEAD is now at 23b6933... gsdfgsdg
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:37    Updated source code to revision: 23b69330c4527209f95f1b4c3aa1f0a7db70cc55
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:37    Finished task 'Checkout Default Repository' with result: Success
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:37    Running pre-build action: VCS Version Collector
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:37    Starting task 'Build' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.maven:task.builder.mvn3'
command 15-Apr-2016 14:33:37    Beginning to execute external process for build 'MavenTest - Merge - Build Job #51 (MERGE-MERGE-JOB1-51)'\n ... running command line: \n/usr/local/maven/bin/mvn --batch-mode -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/atlassian/bamboo/temp/MERGE-MERGE-JOB1 clean test\n ... in: /opt/atlassian/home/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/MERGE-MERGE-JOB1\n ... using extra environment variables: \nbamboo_planRepository_1_branch=master\nbamboo_repository_revision_number=23b69330c4527209f95f1b4c3aa1f0a7db70cc55\nMAVEN2_HOME=/usr/local/maven\nbamboo_resultsUrl=https://bamboo.solveka.com.tr/browse/MERGE-MERGE-JOB1-51\nbamboo_capability_system_jdk_JDK8=/usr/java/sunjdk8\nbamboo_capability_system_jdk_JDK7=/usr/java/sunjdk7\nbamboo_repository_9764866_name=MavenTest\nbamboo_planRepository_1_name=MavenTest\nbamboo_build_working_directory=/opt/atlassian/home/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/MERGE-MERGE-JOB1\nbamboo_buildKey=MERGE-MERGE-JOB1\nbamboo_repository_9764866_git_username=\nbamboo_shortPlanName=Merge\nbamboo_planRepository_name=MavenTest\nbamboo_repository_9764866_branch_name=master\nbamboo_buildNumber=51\nbamboo_shortJobName=Build Job\nbamboo_buildResultsUrl=https://bamboo.solveka.com.tr/browse/MERGE-MERGE-JOB1-51\nbamboo_planRepository_repositoryUrl=ssh://git@stash.solveka.com.tr:7999/merge/maventest.git\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_mkdir=/bin/mkdir\nbamboo_agentId=7929857\nbamboo_planName=MavenTest - Merge\nbamboo_capability_system_jdk_JDK_1_8_0_40=/usr/java/latest\nbamboo_shortPlanKey=MERGE\nbamboo_shortJobKey=JOB1\nbamboo_planRepository_revision=23b69330c4527209f95f1b4c3aa1f0a7db70cc55\nbamboo_repository_previous_revision_number=add354668126e0c70ad8ac30b217a439afe40d21\nbamboo_buildTimeStamp=2016-04-15T14:33:36.362+03:00\nbamboo_repository_9764866_revision_number=23b69330c4527209f95f1b4c3aa1f0a7db70cc55\nbamboo_planRepository_previousRevision=add354668126e0c70ad8ac30b217a439afe40d21\nM2_HOME=/usr/local/maven\nbamboo_buildResultKey=MERGE-MERGE-JOB1-51\nbamboo_repository_git_branch=master\nbamboo_repository_branch_name=master\nbamboo_buildPlanName=MavenTest - Merge - Build Job\nbamboo_planRepository_1_revision=23b69330c4527209f95f1b4c3aa1f0a7db70cc55\nbamboo_repository_name=MavenTest\nJAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest\nbamboo_planRepository_branch=master\nbamboo_agentWorkingDirectory=/opt/atlassian/home/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir\nbamboo_capability_system_git_executable=/usr/bin/git\nbamboo_planRepository_1_previousRevision=add354668126e0c70ad8ac30b217a439afe40d21\nbamboo_repository_git_username=\nbamboo_repository_9764866_git_repositoryUrl=ssh://git@stash.solveka.com.tr:7999/merge/maventest.git\nbamboo_planRepository_1_type=stash-rep\nbamboo_planRepository_branchName=master\nbamboo_repository_9764866_previous_revision_number=add354668126e0c70ad8ac30b217a439afe40d21\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_atlas_mvn=/opt/atlassian-plugin-sdk/bin/atlas-mvn\nbamboo_planRepository_type=stash-rep\nbamboo_planRepository_1_username=\nbamboo_repository_git_repositoryUrl=ssh://git@stash.solveka.com.tr:7999/merge/maventest.git\nbamboo_repository_9764866_git_branch=master\nuseMavenReturnCode=false\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_mvn3_Maven_3=/usr/local/maven\nbamboo_working_directory=/opt/atlassian/home/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/MERGE-MERGE-JOB1\nbamboo_planKey=MERGE-MERGE\nbamboo_planRepository_1_repositoryUrl=ssh://git@stash.solveka.com.tr:7999/merge/maventest.git\nbamboo_planRepository_username=\nbamboo_capability_system_jdk_JDK_1_8=/usr/java/latest\nbamboo_planRepository_1_branchName=master\nPATH=/usr/java/latest/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin\n
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO]                                                                         
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] Building maventest 1.0-SNAPSHOT
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] 
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ maventest ---
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] Deleting /data/atlassian/home/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/MERGE-MERGE-JOB1/target
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] 
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ maventest ---
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [debug] execute contextualize
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /data/atlassian/home/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/MERGE-MERGE-JOB1/src/main/resources
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] 
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ maventest ---
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /data/atlassian/home/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/MERGE-MERGE-JOB1/target/classes
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] 
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ maventest ---
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [debug] execute contextualize
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /data/atlassian/home/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/MERGE-MERGE-JOB1/src/test/resources
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] 
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ maventest ---
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:40    [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /data/atlassian/home/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/MERGE-MERGE-JOB1/target/test-classes
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    [INFO] 
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ maventest ---
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    [INFO] Surefire report directory: /data/atlassian/home/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/MERGE-MERGE-JOB1/target/surefire-reports
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    -------------------------------------------------------
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41     T E S T S
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    -------------------------------------------------------
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Running MERGE.maventest.AppTest
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.034 sec
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Results :
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    [INFO] Total time: 3.029s
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    [INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 15 14:33:41 EEST 2016
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    [INFO] Final Memory: 17M/144M
build   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Parsing test results under /opt/atlassian/home/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/MERGE-MERGE-JOB1...
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Finished task 'Build' with result: Success
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Running post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Running post build plugin 'Artifact Copier'
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Publishing an artifact: JAR file
error   15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Unable to publish artifact [JAR file]: 
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    The artifact hasn't been successfully published after 0s
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Running post build plugin 'npm Cache Cleanup'
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Running post build plugin 'Clover Results Collector'
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Running post build plugin 'Docker Container Cleanup'
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Finalising the build...
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Stopping timer.
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Build MERGE-MERGE-JOB1-51 completed.
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Running on server: post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Running on server: post build plugin 'Build Hanging Detection Configuration'
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:41    Running on server: post build plugin 'Clover Delta Calculator'
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:42    Running on server: post build plugin 'Maven Dependencies Postprocessor'
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:42    All post build plugins have finished
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:42    Generating build results summary...
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:42    Saving build results to disk...
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:42    Logging substituted variables...
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:42    Indexing build results...
simple  15-Apr-2016 14:33:42    Finished building MERGE-MERGE-JOB1-51.

// pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>MERGE</groupId>
  <artifactId>maventest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>maventest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

and my folders in the maven project:

[image]

How to make it create a jar file? Are my java files in wrong place or am I doing something wrong?

UPDATE: Added log and pom.xml to the post

Comment: Best is to post the log output as text and not as images...cause some people are restricted...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maven uses build phases such as compile, test, package and install.

Your build seems to only execute until the "test" phase.
The package phase, which will usually follow the test phase, is never executed in your case.

Try to change your change your configuration to run "mvn clean install" for example.

This answer might also help you: [Bamboo: how to produce maven artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597736/bamboo-how-to-produce-maven-artifact)

Comment: I've just realised that I had to state it in "goal". Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I did not specify "package" in MAVEN goal. One can do it by "Configure Plan" menu of a build plan.

[image]