# Unable to connect mysql to spring boot project

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-tool-suite

i am following this https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/ guide to connect mysql db to spring boot project

but getting following error when running the application, i am generating spring starter project and only selecting web, mysql and jpa boxes while creating project via spring tool suite

```
2018-03-28 16:48:42.125 ERROR 15452 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : Failed to load driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from HikariConfig class classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@782830e
2018-03-28 16:48:42.128  WARN 15452 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
2018-03-28 16:48:42.130  INFO 15452 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-03-28 16:48:42.142  INFO 15452 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-03-28 16:48:42.143 ERROR 15452 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:

    Property: driverclassname
    Value: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
    Reason: Unable to set value for property driver-class-name

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

following is application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
```

and pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>proj.mine</groupId>
    <artifactId>training-app-2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>training-app-2</name>
    <description>traning practive app</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**EDIT:** Added spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in application.properties, error still persists

```
2018-03-28 17:55:05.641  WARN 3140 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2018-03-28 17:55:05.643  INFO 3140 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-03-28 17:55:05.656  INFO 3140 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-03-28 17:55:05.662 ERROR 3140 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at proj.mine.TrainingApp2Application.main(TrainingApp2Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:224) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:176) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:81) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: can you remove the scope as runtime for mysql-connector-java and try?

Comment: just tried, still same error

Comment: can you add spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver to application.properties and try?

Comment: added but still, its throwing exception. Edited the exception

Comment: I was getting same error, i used "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" so i changed to "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" and now its working

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like the application may not be running with the correct classpath as it seem to be having difficulty locating the mysql driver. Are you trying to run the application through the IDE?

Try running the application via maven using the command line from the project's directory:

> ./mvnw spring-boot:run

If this works then it's a problem with the IDE, for some reason it's not providing the correct classpath when running your application. I'm not familiar with STS but in IntelliJ there are options like "auto import pom" to keep the IDE's view of the project in sync with the pom.

Comment: Yes, it seems like it was STS bug, as suggested by one of my colleague first I deleted the .m2 folder and then ran `mvn clean install` and then `mvn spring-boot:run` and the application now runs fine.

Comment: Yes, my error was the IDE run the project whit jre and run in terminal I used the jdk and all ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Try to add mysql connector driver version and remove scope tag from:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I did this earlier it didn't work, somehow it was STS ide issue :/

Comment: Try '_provided_' scope in the **pom.xml**

Comment: Adding the dependency in my POM worked for me on Intellij, thanks!

Comment: @shellbye, connection driver could not be inserted in pom.xml automatic. You should add connection driver according to database you use.

Answer (score 4):

FYI, I encountered a similar problem when I changed my Spring Boot app from H2 to mySQL.

I was using Gradle (instead of Maven).  I, too, was using STS.

I simply forgot to run `Refresh Gradle Project` after I added this to my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    ...
    // Use MySQL Connector-J
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
```

The problem went away after doing a "Refresh Gradle Project" and rebuilding/restarting my app.

Answer (score 3):

com.zaxxer.hikari.**HikariDataSource** requires **spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc** dependency, so add it to your **pom.xml**:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you missing MySQL connector dependency so add it into dependencies tag on pom.xml file and run the project again. It may fix your problem.

```
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency> `
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the `pom.xml` file with DB version and the database:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>mysql</groupId> 
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.44</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when building via intellij --> build --> build artifacts.
I was able to solve this by using maven --> package to creating the jar.

Also please check this: [Bamboo: how to produce maven artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597736/bamboo-how-to-produce-maven-artifact)